# How to pass a member function to a class constructor?

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I want to pass my class Worker a pointer to a funtion, but something is wrong when im calling the constructor...

Worker.h

```
class Worker : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
Worker(void (*process)());

public slots:
void work();

signals:
void error(QString error);
void paused();

private:
void (*_task)();
};
```

Worker.cpp:

```
Worker::Worker(void (*task)())
{
_task = task;
}

void Worker::work()
{
_task();
paused();
}
```

This is what i want to do...
Worker should perform a function call of any function.
(Update is a void without attributes, not static or const etc.)

Main.cpp:

```
_worker = new Worker(someClass->Update());
```

Comment: You might want to learn about [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind).

Comment: As for your problem, you *call* the `Update` function. You do not pass the function to the constructor, but its result.

Answer (score 4):

First, when a function is a `non static` member function of a class, its first argument is the object from which its called.

In your example, the real code for your function `Update()` from the object `someClass` is "void Update(&someClass)"

Secondly, when you do `Update()`, you call the function and so, takes its return in your `Worker` constructor.

To use member function pointers, the syntax is : `&ClassType::FunctionName`

To use 'normal' function pointers, the syntax is : `&FunctionName`

In your exemple, you can for exemple turn Update function to static and change your constructor like this :

```
_worker = new Worker(&someClassType::Update);
```

Like someone said in the comments, if you want to improve your code, learn about std::function from C++11

Answer (score 0):

Just a variant of Félicie's answer.

If you want to be able to pass methods operating on arbitrary objects, the C++11 way will be to use `std::function` and `std::bind`.

If for any reason you must use a pre C++11 system, you will have to revert to the C-ish style of passing arbitrary arguments, the good old `void *` type:

```
void someClassUpdateWrapper(void *obj) {
    SomeClassType someClass = static_cast<SomeClassType *>(obj);
    someClass->Update();
}
```

You will have to slightly change your declarations:

```
class Worker : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
Worker(void (*process)(), void *obj);

...

private:
void (*_task)();
void *_obj;
};
```

then:

```
Worker::Worker(void (*task)(), void *obj;)
{
_task = task;
_obj = obj;
}

void Worker::work()
{
_task(_obj);
paused();
}
```

and finaly:

```
_worker = new Worker(someClassUpdateWrapper, static_cast<void *>(someClass));
```

But this looses all the possible type controls allowed by the C++11 way - the reason why `std::function` and `std::bind` were invented...